# Cavalieri's Principle

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In my measure theory class, my teacher wrote the following theorem:

> Theorem (Cavalieri's Principle): Let $f:\Omega\to [0,+\infty]$ be a measurable function. Then for every monotone, $\mathscr{C}^1$, function $\Phi:\mathbb{R}_+\to\mathbb{R}_+ $ which satisfies $\Phi(0)=0$, we have
>   $$\int_\Omega \Phi(f(x))\:\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+} \Phi'(\lambda)\rho_f(\lambda)\:\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$

Also, he has defined $\rho_f$ as the following function:
$$\lambda\mapsto \mu(\{x\in\Omega\:|\:f(x)>\lambda\}),$$
where $\mu$ is Lebesgue's measure.

I (kind of) understand this theorem but I don't know why it is called Cavalieri's principle. It does not seem related to Cavalieri's principle to me. Am I missing some intuition here?

Comment: For starters, with $\Phi(x)=x$, see my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822019/why-does-the-identity-mathbbex-mathbbe-left-int-mathbb1-u-leq-x/2822043#2822043). Recall that Cavalieri's principle says that two regions over the same $y$-interval have the same area when they have the same cross-sectional lengths for each $y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is nice. However, it seems to me that there may be some kind of intuition here which holds for $\Phi\neq \text{Id}$.

Comment: The rest is the usual "change of variables" push-forward of the measure by $\Phi$.   Try \begin{align*}\int_\Omega \Phi(f(x))\,dx &= \int_0^\infty \mu(\{x: \Phi(f(x))>y\})dy = \int_0^\infty \mu(\{x: f(x)>\Phi^{-1}(y)\})\,dy\\ &= \int_0^\infty \mu(\{x:f(x)>\lambda\})\Phi'(\lambda)\,d\lambda\,.\end{align*}