# Cavalieri's principle for compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, geometry, measure-theory

I've thinking how to solve the following:

> Suppose $K_1$ and $K_2$ two compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that their volume is well defined. Suppose the intersections of A and B with any parallel plane to $xy$ have the same area. Prove that $Vol A= Vol B$

My attempt:
Using compactness there exists a finite open cover for each one, so that 
$$ A= \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} O_i \quad B= \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} V_i $$
Also, there is a plane $P$ such that $Area(P \cap O_i)=Area(P\cap V_i)$, so proving $Vol A = Vol B$ means to prove that for some $1\leq i\leq k$, $Vol (O_i) = Vol (V_i)$. But can't figure it out how to assemble something coherent, there are just ideas. Like we can also consider a funcition $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for an interval $I$ in A (or B), $f(t)$ assigns the area corresponding to the intersection of plane $z=t$ and use integrals, but can't ensure that such interval always exists. Any ideas?

Found this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836970/cavalieris-principle), can it be of any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The indicator functions $\ I_A\ $ and $\ I_B\ $ are integrable over $\ \mathbb{R}^3\ $,
\begin{align}
VolA=\int_{\mathbb{R^3}}I_A(x,y,z)\,dxdydz=\int_0^\infty\int _{\mathbb{R^2}} I_A(x,y,z)\,dxdydz\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ \displaystyle\int _{\mathbb{R^2}} I_A(x,y,z)\,dxdy\ $ is the area of the intersection of $\ A\ $ with the plane at height $\ z\ $ above the $\ xy\ $ plane and parallel to it.  The same identities, of course, also hold for $\ B\ $.

Comment: So the idea is that because of the intersection happens at the same height $1_A = 1_B$ ?

Comment: No, that would imply $\ A=B\ $. You're told only that the *areas*  of the intersection of any plane $\ z=c\ $ with $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are the same, which means that $\ \displaystyle\int _{\mathbb{R^2}} I_A(x,y,c)\,dxdy= \displaystyle\int _{\mathbb{R^2}} I_B(x,y,c)\,dxdy\ $ for all $\ c\ $.  The two intersections don't even have to have the same shape.

Comment: You're right! thanks a lot!!