# Expectation as expectation of indicator in Hoeffding Identity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, covariance

I am confused by a step in the proof of the Hoeffding identity as provided in the book by [Denuit, Dhaene, Goovaerts and Kaas](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047001492X). The following is a screen shot of the beginning of the proof:
[image]

I am confused about the transition from the second last to last step here. If $X$ was a non-negative random variable, then it follows that 
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \mathbb{E}\left ( \int_0^{\infty} 1_{u \le X} du \right )
$$
but the result here seems to hold for non-negative random variables. A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2822019/151735), but the accepted solution is just for the non-negative case, unless I have missed something. I'm looking for a clear justification of the last step highlighted in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rest on the fact that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\mathbf 1\{u\leqslant X_1\}-\mathbf 1\{u\leqslant X_2\}\right)du=X_1-X_2,
$$
which can be seen by dealing with the cases $X_1\leqslant X_2$ and $X_2\lt X_1$.