# Covariance of Marshall-Olkin random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Assume $X, Y$ to be random variables with Marshall-Olkin bivariate exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and $\lambda_{12} > 0$.

It is known that the following distributions hold: $$ \mathbb{P}(X > x, Y > y) = e^{-\lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 y - \lambda_{12} \max(x,y)}$$

$$ \mathbb{P}(X > x) = e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_{12})x}$$

$$ \mathbb{P}(Y > y) = e^{-(\lambda_2 + \lambda_{12})y}$$

I'm interested in finding the $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, for which I'm following the [Hoeffding's Identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615279/proof-of-hoeffdings-covariance-identity):

$$ Cov(X,Y) = \int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left[ \mathbb{P}(X \leq x, Y \leq y) - \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y)\mathbb{P}(X \leq x) \right]dydx$$

It's clear that the identity holds for the right tail:

$$ Cov(X,Y) = \int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left[ \mathbb{P}(X > x, Y > y) - \mathbb{P}(Y > y)\mathbb{P}(X > x) \right]dydx$$

By just plugging in the known facts we get that

$$ Cov(X,Y) = \int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left[ e^{-\lambda_1 x - \lambda_2 y - \lambda_{12} \max(x,y)} - e^{-(\lambda_1 + \lambda_{12})x} e^{-(\lambda_2 + \lambda_{12})y} \right]dydx$$

It is known that $Cor(X,Y) = \frac{\lambda_{12}}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_{12}}$. However, this seem to diverge, [according to WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double%20integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22integrand%22%7D%20-%3E%22e%5E(-11*x%20-%2019*y%20-%2017*max(x,y))%20-%20(e%5E(-11*x%20-%2017*x))*(%20e%5E(-19*y%20-%2017*y))%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart1%22%7D%20-%3E%22-999%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend1%22%7D%20-%3E%22999%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22intvariable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22y%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangestart2%22%7D%20-%3E%22-999%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22DoubleIntegral%22,%20%22rangeend2%22%7D%20-%3E%22999%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22,%20%22double%20integral%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D).

**What am I missing or where am I wrong?**

Comment: Of course $X>0$ and $Y>0$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did Oh that's right.. that's probably the answer of what I missed. Thanks!