# Hoeffding's Covariance Identity

Tags: probability, probability-theory, covariance

I want to prove that theorem. I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615279/proof-of-hoeffdings-covariance-identity) post. And it would suffice to prove that $$\text{Cov}\left(X,Y\right)=\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}\int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{Cov}\left(1_{\left\{ X\leq x\right\} },1_{\left\{ Y\leq y\right\} }\right) \, dx \, dy$$ Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Please read here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2243993?seq=1

Comment: @АлександрПальма here is about extensions of the theorem. And equality from above is considered as a fact, without proof

Comment: There is some workaround if you need it.

Comment: First, try a simple lemma. Show that $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E(1_{X\le x})dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X\le x)dx.$

Comment: As the next step expand $Cov(X, Y)$ as $E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$ and see how the above lemma can be useful (you would also need an analogue of the above lemma).